# Filter using date range and keyword in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am trying to implement filtering data using date and keyword in Angular Js. For the keyword search I used ng-model and filter and got it working well.I found out I should use a custom filter for date filtering but did not understand date formatting. Why do we multiply date with 1000?

Answer (score 0):

You divide the date by 1000 because the date timestamps are in milliseconds. So if you have a date timestamp of 11000 then that's 11 seconds (11000/1000 = 11).